# Pass the password to the openssl command that generates the keystore

Tags: ssh, automation, openssl

have the following command that transform the certificate and private key from PEM to pkcs12 format and store them in a keystore

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -chain -in mycert.pem -inkey mykey.pem -out keystore.p12 -name namename-CAfile mycert.pem
```

This command is sent via SSH and the terminal responds with requesting a password for the store which I can not respond to from my remote tool I tried this but did not work

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -chain -in mycert.pem -inkey mykey.pem -out keystore23.p12 -name namename-CAfile mycert.pem -storepass somepass
```

Any of the following solutions would suffice :

1- Send the password directly by passing an argument to the openssl tool
2- Send the password to the terminal via one command only

Comment: Doesn't `-passout pass:MyPKCS12P@ssw0rd` work?

Comment: Well I chcked the documentation and it said -passwrod p , -passout p

Comment: I found this to work -password pass:YourPassword

Comment: Write it up as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the below syntax :

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -chain -in mycert.pem -inkey mykey.pem -out keystore23.p12 -name namename-CAfile mycert.pem -password pass:<your_password>
```

Check out this [link](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/openssl.html#Pass-Phrase-Options) for more info.